# Android - center title before anything else

Tags: android, center, title

again!
I want to center the title of my application in Android. I know I can use a custom layout, or/and programmatically (`((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`)

Anyway, regardless of the way I use to do this, the title is centered with a small delay after the window is loaded, which I don't like. So, my question: is there a method for centering the text of the title bar before anything else. I don't want to open the application, see the text at the left, then after a few seconds, see it how is being centered on the superior bar.
I also use a custom theme that specifies the style of the title, so. Inside the style file I tried `<item name="android:gravity">center</item>` but it doesn't work.

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">
        @style/WindowTitleBackground
    </item>
</style>
</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
<style name="WindowTitleBackground">
   <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm afraid you can only modify in code the title gravity. It doesn't matter how you set the gravity in the style because in the layout for the title bar the title `TextView` declares the layout gravity(to `center_vertical`) **after** the `style` attribute so it will override any gravity attribute you may set on it in a custom style.